# Scrapy Selector has select() method?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

While running the latest version of Scrapy and using `HtmlXPathSelector` to do my Xpath extraction, I notice from the logs that `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated.

So after changing the desired node (let's call it $myNode) to be a Selector instance rather than a `HtmlXPathSelector` instance, I would expect that $myNode.select() would give an error, since, according to [the API](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors-ref), the Selector class has only an `xpath()` method and not a `select()` method.

Yet the `select()` method continues to function. Indeed, if I do a `dir()` on a Selector instance, `select()` is right there as a method of this class.

Is this an omission from the API document? Or it was left out intentionally to try get users to explicitly use `xpath()` or `css()` depending on their query type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the source, Luke!](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/)

Whenever you are not sure, look into the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c9d7386a32aeb4bc7fe9654d194651eee1ede56c/scrapy/selector/unified.py#L155). `select()` is marked as "deprecated", `xpath()` should be used instead:

```
@deprecated(use_instead='.xpath()')
def select(self, xpath):
    return self.xpath(xpath)
```

This was done intentionally for the smoother transition to the newer Scrapy versions.

---

Note that, starting from `0.24.0`, the `response` variable available in the Scrapy spider callback has `Selector`'s method shortcuts:

```
def parse(self, response):
    response.xpath("//title/text()")
    response.css("div.content")
```

Related issue:

- [Make "xpath" and "css" Selector methods available on response](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/554)

Comment: Yes - that was going to be my follow-up question: Should we extract xpath and css using response (as shown in the Scrapy tutorial and your example above), or by instantiating Selector()?

Comment: @Pyderman if are using Scrapy >= 0.24.0, use response shortcuts - this would basically just save you a line of code and, well, make it more readable and "scrapic".

Comment: I see. Yet if I take the out-of-date example given here: http://bit.ly/1Rr79TD , commenting out the instantiation of HtmlXPathSelector, and setting titles = response.xpath("//span[@class='pl']"), scrapy returns empty lists for each list and title key of each item. Why so?

Comment: @Pyderman the example should be rewritten to smth like https://gist.github.com/alecxe/87fcfafbc3a46f38155c. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, I appreciate the full-working example.